# How can I link from one worksheet to another in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with two worksheets.

- Worksheet A contains a big list of people with `name`, `e-mail`, `age`, `phone number` etc.
- Worksheet B contains a small list with specific people and only `e-mail` as an identifier.

I would like to be able to add a link **automatically** for people in Worksheet B which can be identified in Worksheet A by `e-mail`. I would like to have a column in worksheet B which adds a link to the same e-mail row item in worksheet A automatically. **Also if new entries are being added to one or both worksheets links should be created without manual work**.

Example:
One entry in Worksheet B contains e-mail `x@y.tld` which can also be found in worksheet A (together with more information). In this case a column for this entry in Worksheet B offers a link to the entry in Worksheet A.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Although not exactly what you're looking for, Lookup:  `IMPORTRANGE`, `FILTER`, `VLOOKUP` and `QUERY`.

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for, a menu option, a function/formula, a script,...?

Comment: I would like to have a column in worksheet B which adds a link to the same e-mail row item in worksheet A automatically. Also if new entries are being added to one or both worksheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here which works for my request: https://www.quora.com/In-Google-Sheets-how-can-a-cell-be-made-to-hyper-link-to-another-cell/answer/Darren-Mac

The formula I was looking for is this:

```
=CONCAT("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../edit#gid=12967183&range=B";MATCH(B2:B;Sheet2!B:B;0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> or click on the link:

[image: WA110677 example]